# ESLint does not recognize root alias (@)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

I've got a pretty much stock Vue CLI app (Typescript + Airbnb ESLint config) and ESLint cannot resolve my root alias (@), but the compiler and vscode have no trouble resolving it. (See below).

[image]

I have another project with a similar setup and using the exact same machine, ESLint has no trouble resolving @. What can I do here?

Comment: Do you have a link to a repo that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: This is a bug in VSCode. The folder that you have open in VSCode needs to be the direct parent of the project (Which it was not in my case).

See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/405